# Is there a way to override Model properties without defining them all again with Kohana?

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

I have the following, for example:

```
class Model_User extends ORM {
    protected $_rules = array(
        'username' => array(
            'not_empty'  => NULL,
            'min_length' => array(6),
            'max_length' => array(250),
            'regex'      => array('/^[-\pL\pN_@.]++$/uD'),
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'not_empty'  => NULL,
            'min_length' => array(5),
            'max_length' => array(30),
        ),
        'password_confirm' => array(
            'matches'    => array('password'),
        ),
    );
}

class Model_UserAdmin extends Model_User {
    protected $_rules = array(
        'username' => array(
            'not_empty'  => NULL,
            'min_length' => array(6),
            'max_length' => array(250),
            'regex'      => array('/^[-\pL\pN_@.]++$/uD'),
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'not_empty'  => NULL,
            'min_length' => array(5),
            'max_length' => array(42),
        ),
    ); 
}
```

In here, `Model_UserAdmin` extends `Model_User` and overrides the max length for password and removes the validation for `password_confirm` (this is not an actual case, but an example).

Is there a better way instead of redefining the entire `$_rules` property/array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `_initialize()` instead of `__construct($id)` if you want to store your UserAdmin model in session (like Auth module does). Serialized ORM objects will not call `__construct()`, so part of your rules will lost. `_initialize()` method sets default values for model properties like table_name, relationships etc

```
protected function _initialize()
{
   // redefine model rules
   $this->_rules['password']['max_length'] = 42 ;
   unset($this->_rules['password_confirm']) ;
   // call parent method
   parent::_initialize();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the child's constructor you can probably overwrite or add array elements to `$this->_rules`, as it will already exist as soon as you create a `Model_UserAdmin` instance.

Specifically, in `Model_UserAdmin` don't define a `protected $rules` so it gets it from its parent, and then in the constructor:

```
$this->_rules['password']['max_length'] = 42 ;
unset($this->_rules['password_confirm']) ;
```

You can also add some sanity check right before to make sure those keys exist, in case you change them in `Model_User` and forget.

It's not exactly elegant but it should work. I do suppose you can create some wrapper functions around it (probably in a `class ORM extends ORM_Core` so they're available when you extend ORM) that modify the rules in a more formal way.

*edit* please look at biakaveron's answer for a tip on where to place the child rules (`_initialize()` instead of the constructor)

Comment: I was thinking this would be the way :( Was hoping Kohana had something for this already.