# kohana add column to inherit model

Tags: kohana-orm

I was wondering how to work with kohana orm and inheritances.

Supose I have a model called Vehicle

$_table_columns with 5 columns

The lets supose I create another model called Car and I want to add 5 more columns to the model. How should I modify the parent $_table_columns variable or should I override it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're looking for something like this `protected $_table_columns = parent::_table_columns + array(...);`. Unfortunatly PHP won't allow for this, so you will have to either override `$_table_columns` and list all 10 columns or override ORM `reload_columns` method like this:

```
public function reload_columns($force = FALSE)
{
   $this->_table_columns = parent::_table_columns + array(...);
   parent::reload_columns($force);
}
```

Comment: Hi Matino, thanks for your response. Why do you say that php wont allow is for the protected property or for the '+' sign? Either way what does the reload_columns does?

Comment: would it be posible to do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859155/is-there-a-way-to-override-model-properties-without-defining-them-all-again-with but with the columns array?

Comment: reload_columns is the native ORM function, where $_table_columns are being initialized. So if you override this function the way I wrote, you could initialize it like you asked.

Comment: Matino, what I did is extend the parent class and on the constructor of the class I did $this->_table_columns = $this->_table_columns + array(...) and after this I called the parent constructor. I seem to be working but then I removed some fields from the array but the model kept loading the fields and that is why I asked this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017337/kohana-columns-introspection/8019155#8019155 which you answer as well so thank you for all your help